# While calling, which database does the UDF (User defined function) automatically refer to in Teradata

Tags: function, teradata, udf

While calling a user defined function, if there is no database explicitly mentioned, which database will be considered? Is there any control setting which specifies which database will be referred to first?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this, in the TD documentation, first priority is given to syslib database, and then to TD_SYSFNLIB.

The udfs in TD_SYSFNLIB come in the system (embedded services functions), and the ones in syslib are customer developed.

If you try to invoke an embedded services function using the function name alone, but you also have a customer-developed UDF with the same name in the current database or in the SYSLIB database, Teradata Database will execute the customer-developed UDF instead of the embedded services function.